# Is there a file picker widget for custom file formats?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm writing a bitmap editor. Each document consists of about 3 bitmap layers and documents are, at the moment, saved as a custom file with a .bme extension. These files can be converted to standard jpg/png files by rendering each bitmap on top of one bitmap and saving the latter.

I need some way for the user to be able to select .bme files they've created already. Is there anything in Android that can make this easier for me?

The only option I can see is to write an activity that creates a list view and write a list adapter that looks for .bme files on disk i.e. a copy of the standard "Media Gallery" app that works for my .bme files. The list adapter will either have to generate a thumbnail preview of the image to show to the user or I'll have to package such a preview in the .bme file when they're created.

This is the only option I can think of. I thought I'd ask in case there is more Android friendly way of doing this. For example, can you add custom file support to the "Media Gallery" app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything in Android that can make this easier for me?

Nothing built in. If it weren't for the extension filter, you could link to [OI File Manager](http://www.openintents.org/en/filemanager).

> This is the only option I can think of.

It seems like a fine, upstanding option.

> For example, can you add custom file support to the "Media Gallery" app?

Not that I am aware of, sorry. Besides, that app is not on all phones.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen OI File Manager used in a few apps. I read a Google engineer commenting that Android doesn't have a file picker widget as you shouldn't be exposing the user to such ugly internal details. The IO File Manager is a bit complex looking for users in this regard and I also can't see any way I can add thumbnails for my .bme files. I guess creating a GridView of files filtered by extension shouldn't be too tough to do.